# AS3 Access Library asset

Tags: actionscript

I am using Flash CS3. In the library of my fla file I have several animated MovieClips. How do I access these from external .as files?

[edit]

To clarify, my fla file has a class definition (Main) which in turn is loading a new class, which in turn is loading another new class. It is this final class that I would like to give access to the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library in flash holds classes of graphic objects. So, any class knowing the names of library classes, can create them with `getDefinitionByName`:

```
//create resource called "myButton" in the library:
var buttonClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("myButton");
var myButton:DisplayObject = new buttonClass() as DisplayObject;
```

But if your external classes have no idea about the names, you should pass those names to them (through constructor argument, setter or public var.)

Comment: I am now getting a reference error: "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable myButton is not defined." Except it is. There's a movieclip called myButton in the library. I have tried exporting it for actionscript but that did not help either.

Comment: I found out what my problem was. I was exporting my movieclips to frame 2 so that my preloader on frame 1 would load quickly. I then tried to access the movieclips on the first frame (before they had loaded). This is why I was getting my errors. Once loaded, the above does word.